# sample vector exactly according to the probability given

Tags: r, sample

I believe there should be a function for this in R. However, I am not able to find it. What I need is to get vectors depending on the probability given. I thought `sample` can do this but it is not what I exactly want.

```
sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4), size = 4, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
```

gives

```
# [1] 1 3 4 2
```

which is correct.

Then I try

```
sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4), size = 8, replace = T, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)) 

# [1] 1 4 4 3 2 3 1 3
```

What I actually need is something like

```
#[1] 1 4 4 2 2 3 1 3
```

OR

```
#[1] 2 3 1 1 4 4 2 3
```

OR something of similar sort where the given vector is divided exactly according to the probability given. So in the given example the output vector should contain `0.25` of every vector in `c(1, 2, 3, 4)`. So if `size = 8` then 0.25 of  it is 2 which should be the length of every element in `c(1, 2, 3, 4)`. Is there already a function in R for this or I would have to write a custom one?

Comment: I suppose you don't want `c(sample(4), sample(4))` ? or `c(replicate(2,sample(4)))` ?

Comment: `sample(rep(1:4, 2))` - you can generalize it further but basically what you want to do is create a vector with the desired number of repetitions and then use sample to permute it.

Comment: @jogo i believe your code would work only for equal number of probability value. (here 0.25). What if I have probability as `c(0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2)` ?

Comment: yes, your example is (till now) also only for equal probabilities. But there is the solution of eipi10 and the comment of Dason, which you can use or (in the case of the Dasons comment) elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want the number of repetitions of each value to be deterministic, rather than random, use `rep` (instead of `sample`) to repeat each value in proportion to its probability in `prob`. Then you can create random permutations of the resulting vector.

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)

prob = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)

# Total sample size
n = 20

result = rep(x, round(n * prob))

[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Then to create, say, 100 random permutations:

```
replicate(100, sample(result))
```

Comment: I think they want it permuted as well but just wrapping the whole thing with `sample` takes care of that

Comment: @Dason exactly! Thanks eipi10. `sample(rep(x, round(n * prob)))` works for me